# I need a font similar to Press Style Serif but not as condensed

Tags: fonts

[image: can anyone provide me with a similar font to press style serif, just not as condensed?]

can anyone provide me with a similar font to press style serif, just not as condensed?

Comment: I tried expanding the font in Illustrator but i don't like messing around with fonts.

Comment: What similarities do you want to retain? The slab serifs? The grunge? The tall x-height? The weird looking 'i'?

Comment: There are a few if you've looked -- Lulo, Nexa Rust, microbrew

Answer (score 0):

Stud is a similar font: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/stud/regular/.

You can always edit the 'press style serif' test in illustrator by expanding the text. You can also look into changing the font by changing the: Kerning, Leading or Horizontal Scale.